# Ionic iOS App WebKit crash in MobileIron Environment

Tags: ios, ionic3, webkit, cfnetwork, mobileiron

My company is deveveloping an Ionic 3 App which is distributed to iOS devices using MobileIron.
When the App is started the first time after install it appears to hang and there is a crash report in the device logs indicating that WebKit was involved in the crash.
After waiting 5 minutes the app starts without problem.
The same App functions without inciden on a non-MobileIron device.

The MobileIron VPN app/connection log shows a similar picture.

How can we best solve this issue?

Thanks.

The crash log shows:

```
Incident Identifier: 9A0F6B00-380A-4707-A303-FAA287736092
CrashReporter Key:   04141dc7075f08c63f8a76b0aa5a2356684c0036
Hardware Model:      iPhone10,4
Process:             com.apple.WebKit.Networking [3123]
Path:                /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/XPCServices/com.apple.WebKit.Networking.xpc/com.apple.WebKit.Networking
Identifier:          com.apple.WebKit.Networking
Version:             8605.3.8 (8605)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Unspecified
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.corp.app [662]


Date/Time:           2018-09-20 14:47:38.7405 +0200
Launch Time:         2018-09-20 14:47:34.6940 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.4.1 (15G77)
Baseband Version:    1.04.80
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000018
VM Region Info: 0x18 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4378525672
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                 0000000104fb0000-0000000104fb4000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...it.Networking

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  2

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001811cbde8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001811cbc60 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018170ee40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018170c908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018162cda8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5   Foundation                      0x00000001820a1674 -[NSRunLoop+ 34420 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x00000001821161a8 -[NSRunLoop+ 512424 (NSRunLoop) run] + 88
7   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001813d5a6c _xpc_objc_main + 516
8   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001813d7b40 xpc_main + 180
9   com.apple.WebKit.Networking     0x0000000104fb35ac 0x104fb0000 + 13740
10  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001810bdfc0 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001811edd78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018138beb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018138bb08 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.network.connections
Thread 2 Crashed:
0   CFNetwork                       0x0000000181f2e438 ConnectionProtocolSetFinalData+ 2376760 (nw_protocol*) + 124
1   CFNetwork                       0x0000000181f2e434 ConnectionProtocolSetFinalData+ 2376756 (nw_protocol*) + 120
2   CFNetwork                       0x0000000181f2c3ec ConnectionProtocolRemoveInputHandler+ 2368492 (nw_protocol*, nw_protocol*, bool) + 112
3   libnetwork.dylib                0x000000018264e4e4 nw_endpoint_flow_failed + 388
4   libnetwork.dylib                0x000000018264ffd4 nw_endpoint_flow_setup_protocols + 1344
5   libnetwork.dylib                0x000000018264c614 -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_flow startWithHandler:] + 4484
6   libnetwork.dylib                0x00000001826a30b4 nw_endpoint_handler_path_change + 10620
7   libnetwork.dylib                0x00000001826a037c nw_endpoint_handler_start + 1176
8   libnetwork.dylib                0x00000001827065c8 __nw_connection_start_block_invoke + 632
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181058aa0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181058a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001810971d4 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$armv81 + 568
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181097af8 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 328
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018109849c _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$armv81 + 332
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001810a046c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$armv81 + 612
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018138be70 _pthread_wqthread + 860
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018138bb08 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001811edd78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018138beb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018138bb08 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001811ed0e8 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181393ed8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$armv81 + 628
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001808a42ec std::__1::condition_variable::__do_timed_wait+ 29420 (std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >) + 96
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000188db56e8 std::__1::cv_status std::__1::condition_variable::wait_until<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >+ 11364072 (std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > const&) + 124
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000188db5598 std::__1::cv_status std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait_until<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>, std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >+ 11363736 (std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > const&) + 112
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000188db50dc bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop+ 11362524 () + 272
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000188db4e18 bmalloc::Scavenger::Scavenger+ 11361816 (std::__1::lock_guard<bmalloc::StaticMutex>&) + 0
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000188db5234 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)(bmalloc::Scavenger*), bmalloc::Scavenger*> >+ 11362868 (void*) + 44
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018138d220 _pthread_body + 272
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018138d110 _pthread_body + 0
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018138bb10 thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001811edd78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018138beb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018138bb08 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018138bb04 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001811edd78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018138beb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018138bb08 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0xfffffffffffffff0
    x4: 0x0000000105132080   x5: 0x0000000000000005   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000001
    x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0xc8bdfff7fc2b0061  x10: 0x000101a1b3deb35d  x11: 0x6b636f7300737365
   x12: 0x736572676f72705f  x13: 0x74656b636f730073  x14: 0x617300776f6c662d  x15: 0x0064656966736974
   x16: 0x0000000181387d94  x17: 0x00000001812b8334  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x00000001053091b0
   x20: 0x00000001053091b0  x21: 0x0000000000000001  x22: 0x00000001053091b0  x23: 0x00000001b24ce000
   x24: 0x00000001053091b0  x25: 0x000000016af62378  x26: 0x00000001b24ce000  x27: 0x0000000105315d30
   x28: 0x00000001b24ce000   fp: 0x000000016af62410   lr: 0x0000000181f2e434
    sp: 0x000000016af62340   pc: 0x0000000181f2e438 cpsr: 0x60000000

Binary Images:
0x104fb0000 - 0x104fb3fff com.apple.WebKit.Networking arm64  <a779288ad6513bcfbac6ce2ed3330a36> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/XPCServices/com.apple.WebKit.Networking.xpc/com.apple.WebKit.Networking
0x105234000 - 0x10526ffff dyld arm64  <b15e536a710732dabfafece44c5685e4> /usr/lib/dyld
```

Comment: Do you have any solution for this issue ?